# Meaning of 'part%04d' in python

Tags: python-3.x, django

hello I am using python but I am Stuck[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHI4S.png)at this point. where I don't know the meaning of this
word "part%04d" in python. that's why I am asking you what is the meaning of this 'part%04d' in python? if you know then plz help me thank you!

Comment: https://pyformat.info/#number_padding

Answer (score 0):

This is likely used in the context of *string formatting*. Likely there is some expression that looks like:

```
'part%04d' % some_number
```

In that case it will format the number (`some_number`) here with leading zeros such that the [number is *padded*](https://pyformat.info/#number_padding) to four digits. For example:

```
>>> 'part%04d' % 1
'part0001'
>>> 'part%04d' % 15
'part0015'
>>> 'part%04d' % 115
'part0115'
>>> 'part%04d' % 3125
'part3125'
>>> 'part%04d' % 3125.3
'part3125'
>>> 'part%04d' % 31254
'part31254'
```